# SF Story identification, short story published 1940s, 1950s, immortal Neanderthal

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to identify a short story written quite some time ago, in the 1940s or 1950s. I remember that there was an immortal Neanderthal hiding in plain sight, pretending to be just an ugly human. It was humorous and well-written.

Any information about the story's name and where it was originally published would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Possibly L. Sprague De Camp's 1939 story "[The Gnarly Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gnarly_Man)"?  Originally published in *Unknown*. In this story the intelligent protagonist Neanderthal was struck by lightning back in the day and became immortal.  After he's discovered by contemporary scientists and outed, he has to go back into hiding when he finds out they plan to dissect him! It has been [anthologized often](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?52284).

Comment: I'm sure that's it. Thanks! I'll look for it in anthology form.

Comment: Yes! There's a second one... from the same period... was it "Old Man Mulligan" by P. Schuyler Miller, by any chance?